# How to draw labels with line in SLD?

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld

I want to be able to draw labels with line. How can i do this?

Just like labels with line of some USA states in Google Maps, labels with red line in right :

[Example from Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/?ll=39.164141,-57.568359&spn=37.283162,86.572266&t=h&z=4)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Please add more details. An illustration perhaps? Your question is rather vague right now.

Answer (score 1):

add a text symbolizer to your rule (the same way you label any other feature) - see http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/lines.html#line-with-default-label for full details.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt mean labels for lines, but lines for labels.